# Nginx Directory Listing - Restrict by IP Address

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

We have a requirement to allow directory listing from few servers and disallow from other ip addresses and all IP addresses should be able to download all files inside the directory.

Can somebody provide the correct nginx config for the same.

```
location / {
root /downloads;
autoindex on;
allow 1.1.1.1;
deny all;
}
```

If I use the above config, only on 1.1.1.1 IP address can directory list from this server and can file download but  from other IP addresses download shows forbidden, due to IP address restriction

Is there a way to overcome this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

As `autoindex` doesn't like to use variables or be in if blocks this is my working solution to your problem

```
geo $geoAutoIndexWhitelist {
    default             0;
    1.1.1.0/24          1;
}

server {
    ...
    root /downloads;
    autoindex off;

    location / {
        if ($geoAutoIndexWhitelist) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /all_downloads/$1 last;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /all_downloads/ {
        internal;
        alias /downloads;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

<strike>You can do it with a combo of [`geo`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_geo_module.html) and [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directives</strike>

```
geo $geoAutoIndexWhitelist {
    default        0;
    1.1.1.1/24     1;
}

map $geoAutoIndexWhitelist $allowAutoIndex {
    1              off;
    0              on;
}

location / {
    root /downloads;
    autoindex $allowAutoIndex;
}
```

So what is going on is we are telling the `autoindex` to get the value from the `allowAutoIndex` `map` directive which is, in turn, using the `geoAutoIndexWhitelist` `geo` directive to return a value based on IP range.

`geoAutoIndexWhitelist` by default returns a 0 unless the IP falls within the subnet range then it returns a 1, more ranges can be added but the returned values should be 0 or 1.

`allowAutoIndex` looks at the `geoAutoIndexWhitelist` and returns off vs. on based on a 0 or 1 result.

Note this ad hoc and untested but should lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your reply and input. I tried adding geo and map section in nginx.conf and location section in my site config  but I am getting error nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$allowAutoIndex" in "autoindex" directive, it must be "on" or "off" in domain.conf

Comment: @Sathish you are correct. I updated my non-working example to a working example.